# how to disable web page cache throughout the servlets

Tags: servlets, caching, response, no-cache

To no-cache web page, in the java controller servlet, I did somthing like this in a method:

```
public ModelAndView home(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(ViewConstants.MV_MAIN_HOME);
    mav.addObject("testing", "Test this string");
    mav.addObject(request);
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
    return mav;
}
```

But this only works for a particular response object. I have many similar methods in a servlet. And  I have many servlets too.

If I want to disable cache throughout the application, what should I do?
(I do not want to add above code for  every single response object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do this [via a filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html)?

> A filter is an object that can transform the header and content (or both) of a request or response.
>
> ...
>
> The main tasks that a filter can perform are as follows:
>
> ...
>
> - Modify the response headers and data. You do this by providing a customized version of the response.

Just register your Filter (class implementing the Filter interface) and modify your response within the [`doFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html) method.

---

**EDIT:** E.g.

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class NoCacheFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest servletRequest, final ServletResponse servletResponse, final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Note that the `@WebFilter` annotation will require Servlet 3.0, otherwise you can register it via your `web.xml`. This path of "/*", would apply to any path of your application, but could be narrowed in scope.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am wondering if all the servlets are the child classes of another servlet, can we do something in the base class?

Comment: @Kurt Yes, that's object-oriented programming ;)